# MariaDB 10.2 crash on innodb table corruption

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I'm running MariaDB 10.2 on Windows and had some hard drive corruption on my server that messed up some innodb tables.  Unfortunately this also affected backups, so I'm trying to dump the tables and restore them.  Problem is, even with force recovery set to 6, the server will crash when it reaches a corrupt row.  Dumping the table with asc and then desc worked for one table, but not for another and any attempt to jump the row with limit and offset still crashes.  I saw that there was a innodb_pass_corrupt_table_action=salvage option in 10.1, but it is deprecated and ignored with 10.2.  Is there a similar setting for 10.2?  Are there any other options to force MySQL to dump the tables?  Thanks!

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com is probably a better place for this type of question.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do.  Posted it here - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227500/mariadb-10-2-crash-on-innodb-table-corruption